# How to insert / retrieve a file stored as a BLOB in a MySQL db using python

Tags: python, mysql, file-io, blob

I want to write a python script that populates a database with some information.  One of the columns in my table is a BLOB that I would like to save a file to for each entry.

How can I read the file (binary) and insert it into the DB using python?  Likewise, how can I retrieve it and write that file back to some arbitrary location on the hard drive?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
thedata = open('thefile', 'rb').read()
sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (theblobcolumn) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (thedata,))
```

That code of course works as written only if your table has just the BLOB column and what
you want to do is INSERT, but of course you could easily tweak it to add more columns,
use UPDATE instead of INSERT, or whatever it is that you exactly need to do.

I'm also assuming your file is binary rather than text, etc; again, if my guesses are
incorrect it's easy for you to tweak the above code accordingly.

Some kind of `SELECT` on `cursor.execute`, then some kind of fetching from the cursor, is how you
retrieve BLOB data, exactly like you retrieve any other kind of data.

Comment: It seems, MySQL has started warning about this sort of thing.  Now one should use "... VALUES (**_binary** %s)"

Answer (score -2):

You can insert and read BLOBs from a DB like every other column type. From the database API's view there is nothing special about BLOBs.

Comment: If a blob has pdf?