# how to compress a python dict to save into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, blob

i have a large python dict, maybe 10MB,  failed to save it in mysqldb, as repr(dict)
i tried zlib.compress, the result string is ill to save mysql.
now how about compress the dict and convert to binary, and save as blob?  any coding sample?

#update
  i tried struct with zlib, about 50% reduced for string of 200k char length.
 test:

```
import zlib, struct, ast

dic={}
for i in xrange(20):
    dic[str(i)]=i
s=zlib.compress(repr(dic), 5)
bs=struct.pack('%ds' %len(s),s)
s2=struct.unpack('%ds' %len(s),bs)[0]
s2=zlib.decompress(s2)
dic2=ast.literal_eval(s2)
assert dic2==dic
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the dict for later, then I would suggest to save the dict in json format which can then be imported back.

Try [mvps suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229393/1864000) to increase the `max_allowed_packet` first.

```
import json 

dicstring = json.dumps(dic) # outputs as a string format
# or
dicobj = json.dumps(dic).encode('utf-8') # outputs in bytes format

# alternatively, to save the file
with open('path/to/file.json', 'wb+') as file:
    file.write(dicobj)
    file.close()
```

to open the file:

```
with open('path/to/file.json','rb') as file:
    dic = json.loads(file.read().decode('utf-8'))
    file.close()
```

to read the string:

```
dic = json.loads(dicstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save your python dictionary as a BLOB field, but you must use parametrized queries, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294496/1734130).

If your blob is larger than 1MB, you may have to increase [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html) on both server and client for BLOBs to work.

However, better method would be to insert your dictionary into another table, one row per key. You may need to create new table or might be able to use some of the existing tables which should be created just for this purpose.

If that new table is properly indexed, you can take advantage of server being able to quickly retrieve your data by key.

Comment: currenty i need deploy it in appengin, like GAE. Modifying  max_allowed_packet is not allowed. i may use kv db instead.