# Inserting and retrieving images into mysql through python

Tags: python, mysql, python-imaging-library

I used this code to insert an image into mysql database and retrieve back the image.
This code works perfectly with no errors , but the problem is even after inserting an image into img table , when I execute the command `select  * from img ;` in the mysql command line it shows no records.

Table created in database;

```sql
create table img(images blob not null);
```

```py
import mysql.connector
import sys
from PIL import Image
import base64
import cStringIO
import PIL.Image

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='abhi',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='cbir')

#image = Image.open('C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg')
with open("C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

#blob_value = open('C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg', 'rb').read()
sql = 'INSERT INTO img(images) VALUES(%s)'    
args = (encoded_string, )
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,args)
sql1='select * from img'
cursor.execute(sql1)
data=cursor.fetchall()
#print type(data[0][0])
data1=base64.b64decode(data[0][0])
file_like=cStringIO.StringIO(data1)
img=PIL.Image.open(file_like)
img.show()

db.close()
```

Comment: In the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) I found that there is a datatype for binary strings (BLOB) and one for character strings (TEXT). Why do you convert your binary string(image) to a character string(base64) and save this as a binary string(BLOB)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert / retrieve a file stored as a BLOB in a MySQL db using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294385/how-to-insert-retrieve-a-file-stored-as-a-blob-in-a-mysql-db-using-python)

Answer (score 7):

```py
import mysql.connector
import sys
from PIL import Image
import base64
import cStringIO
import PIL.Image

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='abhi',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='cbir')

image = Image.open('C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg')
blob_value = open('C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg', 'rb').read()
sql = 'INSERT INTO img(images) VALUES(%s)'    
args = (blob_value, )
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,args)
sql1='select * from img'
db.commit()
cursor.execute(sql1)
data=cursor.fetchall()
print type(data[0][0])
file_like=cStringIO.StringIO(data[0][0])
img=PIL.Image.open(file_like)
img.show()

db.close()
```

This code works fine

Comment: Please cleanse the code. For example, from PIL import Image and import PIL.Image.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import mysql.connector
import base64
import io

import PIL.Image
with open('lemonyellow_logo.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    photo = f.read()
encodestring = base64.b64encode(photo)
db= mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password="lyncup",host="localhost",database="demo")
mycursor=db.cursor()
sql = "insert into sample values(%s)"
mycursor.execute(sql,(encodestring,))
db.commit()
sql1="select * from sample"
mycursor.execute(sql1)
data = mycursor.fetchall()
data1=base64.b64decode(data[0][0])
file_like=io.BytesIO(data1)
img=PIL.Image.open(file_like)
img.show()
db.close()
```

Comment: It's always better to add a little explaination to the answer

Comment: HI  DaFois ! how are you i think, we can store the file or image only for encrypted data type .  first we must read the file for binarycode. so use import base64 with open('.jpg', 'rb') , as and then encrypted base64.b64encode(photo), then store to mysql.     If you want to show image from mysql using below code for "select * from sample", coming data is encrypt so we decrypt base64.b64decode(data[0][0]). then converto bytecode. because it come from string. then we open image like file PIL.Image.open(file_like), PIL mean for pillow ,this module use store image into mysql. then show. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
import pyautogui
import time
import base64

def byte_string(image_name):
      with open(image_name, 'rb') as image_file:
          encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
      return encoded_string

def insertBLOB(image_id, image_name, image):
    print("Inserting BLOB into my_images table")
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                        user="root",
                        password="Rushi@2001",
                        database = 'my_images',
                        port = 3306)

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_insert_blob_query = " INSERT INTO image_data (image_id, image_name, image) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"

        binary_image = byte_string(image)
        print(len(binary_image))

        # Convert data into tuple format
        insert_blob_tuple = (image_id, image_name, binary_image)
        result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_blob_query, insert_blob_tuple)
        connection.commit()
        print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into my_images table", result)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed inserting BLOB data into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")


insertBLOB(1,'img0',"C:\\Users\\hulag\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python_sql\\images\\img0.png")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).