# How to display a picture from mysql database using python?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I want to display a picture I already saved on the table img, but it gives me an error

> cannot identify image file

When it try to open the `file_like`.
Cursor and connection use the connection and password to mysql database.
With the following code I wanted to display the picture. What's wrong with it, or is there even a better/easier way?

```
sql1='select * from img'
connection.commit()
cursor.execute(sql1)
data2=cursor.fetchall()

file_like=cStringIO.StringIO(data2[0][0])

img1=PIL.Image.open(file_like,mode='r').convert('RGB')
img1.show()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `io.BytesIO` instead of `cstringIO` it works fine, also without decoding and encoding. And I also changed type from `blob` to `mediumblob`, which allows bigger pictures.

```
import pymysql
import io
from PIL import Image

connection=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                 user="root",
                 passwd="root",
                 db="test")
cursor=connection.cursor()
sql1 = 'select * from table'
cursor.execute(sql1)
data2 = cursor.fetchall()

file_like2 = io.BytesIO(data2[0][0])

img1=Image.open(file_like2)
img1.show()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: interesting. How big is your pic? A sidenote regarding your post: pls. use codesnippets only for HTML/JS/CSS. For all other code use code sample (the `{ }` symbol), because you can't actually run Python in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the picture is ~1.3MB

Comment: You can click on edit to change that. Also there's still the useless `connection.commit()`.There's nothing to commit here. You only commit after executing insert or update statements.

Comment: This case is still a mystery for me. Now I checked it with a larger pics (yesterday I tested with a small pic of 38kB, now with 1.37MB and 4.71MB) (had to change column type to medium_blob). I  still used `cStringIO.StringIO` as in my answer above and could read the image. I tested both cases, with encoding/decoding and without and both worked fine. So `cStringIO.StringIO`  dosen't really seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and got the same error. So first I saved an image to my db. When I saved it I used base64 encoding and then got the same error when I tried to read. To save I used the code from [Inserting and retrieving images into mysql through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141718/inserting-and-retrieving-images-into-mysql-through-python), and your code also looks like you got it from the same question/answer.

In this case, the solution is simple. You have to decode the data, that's the part missing in the other answer.
So do a `base64.b64decode(data2[0][0])`:

```
import MySQLdb
import base64
from PIL import Image
import cStringIO

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="root",
                     db="test")
# select statement with explicit select list and where clause instead of select * ...
sql1='select img from images where id=1'  
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
data2=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
db.close()

file_like=cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(data2[0][0]))

img1=Image.open(file_like,mode='r').convert('RGB')
img1.show()
```

Comment: The proposed decoding gives an 'incorrect Padding' Error. Could this have something to do with the python 2.7?

Comment: I also used Python 2.7 to test your code and my answer. And I used the Python program as in the linked question to write the image with base64 encoding to the db. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: my whole answer was actually based on the assumption that you used the code in the linked question, including base64encoding. Was my assumption correct?

Comment: Yes i used the code from the answer, where it says, that it works fine. Just instead of mysql connector, I use pymysql.connect because of the picturesize.

Comment: But where is the base64 encoding when you load the picture into the table?

Comment: and you also used base64encode when you saved the image? It only makes sense as a pair. You mention the picturesize. Could you try with a small picture?

Comment: your last comment came when I just wrote my last comment. The encoding is here : `with open("C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())` (in the code of the linked question)

Comment: Any progress? I see now, in the answer there was no encoding/decoding at all. I started with the code from the question (which contained encoding) to write the pic into the db and after getting the error with the code from the answer I added decoding. The part that was actualy missing in the other question was the commit! If you splitted writing and reading into two programs, I hope there's a commit in the write part of your code. I see a misplace connection.commit() in your question. Is the picture actually in the db?