# How to retrieve an image from mysql to PyQt4 with python3?

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4

I want to show an image from mysql db on my pyqt4 application. I researched some pages about this topic. But I can not get that. I want to show the image on qlabel.

I have gui file and a callpage.py

From callpage.py I want to show like this:

```
self.ui.labelPicture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img))
```

[How to display a picture from mysql database using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814814/how-to-display-a-picture-from-mysql-database-using-python)

[How to insert / retrieve a file stored as a BLOB in a MySQL db using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294385/how-to-insert-retrieve-a-file-stored-as-a-blob-in-a-mysql-db-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking for 2 question. Here are two steps, the first involves you retrieving the base64 image, the second one is the actuall pyqt code.

**1)** First you need to get your your sql query as `base64`

Which is described well here: [How to display a picture from mysql database using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814814/how-to-display-a-picture-from-mysql-database-using-python)

**2)** Populate a `QPixmap` and pass it to your label

```
pm = QtGui.QPixmap()
pm.loadFromData(base64.b64decode(b64_data))
self.ui.labelPicture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(pm))
```

Comment: All right. I understand why my comment/answer is deleted. I am a newbie. :) Okay. Now my actual problem is there is no image on the label widget. it is getting empty. How can I sure that my code is working?