# Handling MySQL BLObs in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, blob

I am accessing a MySQL database (V5.5) via a Python program for generating bespoke reports. The standard fields (int, varchar, datetime, etc.) present no problem - in general I am putting these into Python lists for subsequent processing. However one table makes extensive use of BLObs; these hold either Binary/HTML/PDF/PNG/CSV data. My problem is how to handle them once they are returned in a SELECT statement. The Binary data needs further processing and the PNG may need to be inserted into a report.

Thanks in advance...

I have tried various things including code based on:- [How to insert / retrieve a file stored as a BLOB in a MySQL db using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294385/how-to-insert-retrieve-a-file-stored-as-a-blob-in-a-mysql-db-using-python)

Te relevant snippets are:-

```
TheData = open("/home/mjh/Documents/DemoData/sjp.bin", 'rb').read()

sql = "Insert into Results (idResults, idClient, TestDateTime, ResultBinary) \
    Values (10, 7, '2014-11-05 14:09:11', %s"

cursor.execute(sql, (TheData,))
```

This comes back with:-

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code you have which can demonstrate the problem? "Dear diary" type questions are not very helpful.

Comment: Added some more information...

Comment: That query looks incomplete. Are you sure that's the entire query? Why no closing bracket on your `VALUES(...)`?